# Take a picture and generate a Bar code to add the picture at the same time

Tags: dslr

I need to take a lot of Products Pictures , I need to generate and adding at the same time that i trigger the photo a Bar Code with, is it posible? Please, teach me

Comment: How do you think to add it to the photo? And what kind of info you want to store in this barcode?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to generate and adding at the same time that i trigger the photo a Bar Code with, is it posible?

It's *possible*, but it might be more trouble than you're willing to go to. You could print a series of bar codes, or display them on a small computer display (possibly driven by a Raspberry Pi or Arduino). However you do it, you could include the bar code in the photo itself. The main difficulty with this approach is keeping the bar code far enough away from the subject to not ruin the image while still ensuring that both the subject and the bar code are in focus.

The other approach, of course, is to add the bar code to the photo after the image has been recorded. There must be lots of ways to do that, depending on whether you need the bar code attached immediately or if it can be added as a post processing step. Important factors here will be what kind of camera you plan to use, how easy it is to incorporate that device into the workflow you develop, whether the camera will be fixed in place with fixed settings, or whether you're going to adjust the position and settings for each shot.

This sounds more like a software development project than a photography problem. For example, someone with modest software development skills could build a smartphone app that takes a photo with the phone's camera and adds the necessary bar code. There's just not enough detail in your question to suggest a specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

Caleb already has a great answer, though I'd like to add my thoughts too ...

### Low tech approach

#### Barcode from image counter

Configure your camera not to reset the counter upon card formatting/change.

1. Create bar codes starting with the next number your camera will create (current number + 1)
2. Take a photo
3. Attach the related bar code to the object
4. Refer to the object by the image number (e.g. DSC_1234)

If you delete a photo, throw the bar code away.

#### Spread sheet mapping image numbers

Configure your camera not to reset the counter upon card formatting/change.

1. Create a spreadsheet mapping the first bar codes to the image number your camera will create next
2. Generate a sequence of this number pair (most spreadsheet programs will increment the numbers for you)
3. Take photos
4. Your table already maps bar code to photo

If you delete a photo, delete the number pair from the table.

You might want to prefix the image counter with a session identifier, for example: 201812001234 = Image DSC_1234 in 12-2018.

#### Arbitrary, incrementing bar code included in the photo

1. Generate bar codes with incrementing or random numbers
2. Place the bar code in front / next to the object
3. Take a photo

This easily allows you to take multiple photos of the same object as well.

### Higher tech approach

#### Camera with WIFI connectivity

Many modern cameras these days come with WIFI connectivity. They can send the images to a file server or allow computers to pull the image.

With a bit of programming you could pull the newest image, generate an ID, print a bar code for that ID and add the ID to the EXIF data of the image. This would also allow you to take multiple photos of the same object if the software is make to give you control on that.

---

How to generate bar codes is beyond this Q&A site, but [Superuser might help with bar codes](https://superuser.com/search?q=bar+codes). How to write code with no knowledge at all is also beyond this network.